# "Horse" Math game

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

For my computer science class final, we have been instructed to make our own game in Python.

> Requirements:
>   1. Needs to use both a “while loop” and a “for x in y loop.”
>   2. Needs to use list to either keep track of information or  score
>   3. Needs to use a function for gameplay, tracking score, both.
>   4. Display some art either at the beginning, after, or in between turns.
>   5. Can be multi player or single player.
>   6. Must carry a complexity commensurate with a final project.

Anyways, I decided to make a game similar to horse in basketball. The object of the game is to find the answer of the math problem before time runs out. If you don't, you get a letter in horse. Once you get all the letters of horse, your game is over.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import random
import time
from timeit import default_timer

print("welcome to Jared's Math Horse game!")

time.sleep(1)

print("You will have to do some basic geometry and algebra problem,and some brain teasers...")

time.sleep(1)

print("For each you get wrong, you get a letter, and it will spell 'HORSE'. Once you get all letters, you lose. ROUND TO THE NEAREST INTEGER!!!!!!!!")

time.sleep(1)
###BEgin actual stuff
how_long = int(input("How many times(problems) do you want to play? (above or equal 5)"))
score = 0
##Problems
problems = ["A cylinder has a radius of 5. It's height is 6. What is the volume?471","A boy buys two shirts. One costs $15 and he pays $27 for both shirts. How much was the 2nd shirt?12","dat boi costs $12 after a 15% discount. What was the original price?14.12","A square pyramid with a height 12 and a side length 5. What is the volume?20","What is the square root of 36?", "What is the roman numeral for 500? QUICK USE GOOGLE!!!D","On a scale of 100-100 how cool is jared?100"  ]


#######End of variables
####Func time
    def horse(score,problem,speed):
    b = input("You have {} seconds. Press enter to begin. Round answers to nearest integer.".format(speed))
    begin = default_timer()
    howfast = default_timer() - begin
    print(random.problem[0,7])
    ##Check answer
    answer = input("What is your answer?:")
    ## Give score


##loops
for x in how_long:
    while True:
    if score !=5:
        a = random.randint(0,7)
        problem = problems[a]
        ##Speed
    speed = int(input("How fast do you want to play?? 1=slow 2=medium 3=FAST"))

    if speed == (1):
        speed = random.randint(30,60)
    if speed == 2:
        speed = random.randint(20,40)
    if speed == 3:
        print("spicy!")
        speed = random.randint(10,30)
        score = horse(score,problem,speed)
    if score == 0:
        print("You have a perfect score. Good work.")
    if score == 1:
        print("You have an H")
    if score == 2:
        print("You have Ho")
    if score == 3:
        print("You have Hor")
    if score == 4:
        print("You have Hors")
    if score == 5:
            print("You have Horse. Game over, loser.")
            break
```

horse()

So. I'm not sure how to make it if you type in the correct answer, you won't get a letter, and move on. I tried used a 'if and' statement and that is it. BTW, the answers to the problems are at the end. Help is *VERY* appreciated. Sorry if I didn't explain this well, I am a noob at this. Haha

Comment: Why are you using a variable that you never created `number_wrong`?

Comment: if `number_wrong == 1`, then your code is going to print a total of 5 times... Is that what you want?

Comment: haha, number_wrong should be "score". thanks

Answer (score 1):

That data structure is a disaster. You would be better off doing something like this. Keep a dict of problem : correctAnswer then get a random key, ask for some user input and time it. You still need to implement the horse logic though.

```
score = 0
maxTime = 3 #how many milliseconds a user has to answer the question to get it right
problems = {
            "A cylinder has a radius of 5. It's height is 6. What is the volume?" : "471",
            "A boy buys two shirts. One costs $15 and he pays $27 for both shirts. How much was the 2nd shirt?" : "12",
            "dat boi costs $12 after a 15% discount. What was the original price?" : "14.12",
            "A square pyramid with a height 12 and a side length 5. What is the volume?" : "20",
            "What is the square root of 36?" : "6",
            "What is the roman numeral for 500? QUICK USE GOOGLE!!!" : "D",
            "On a scale of 100-100 how cool is jared?" : "100"
            }


for i in range(how_long):
    startTime = time.time()
    thisProblem = random.choice(list(problems.keys()))
    answer = input(thisProblem + ": ")
    endTime = time.time()

    totalTime = round(endTime - startTime, 2)


    correctAnswer = problems[thisProblem]
    if answer == correctAnswer and totalTime < maxTime:
        print("Correct!, you took", totalTime, "ms to answer")
        score += 1
    elif answer != correctAnswer:
        print("Incorrect!, the correct answer was", correctAnswer)
    elif totalTime > maxTime:
        print("Correct, but you took", totalTime, "ms to answer but are only allowed", maxTime, "ms")
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you